# Laravel throwing 404 for an existing route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

Can someone help me understand what is wrong with these routes:-

From the list of these routes, the third and the last one returns 404. There is no issue with the controllers. They show up as expected when I run `php artisan route:list`.

```
Route::get('/uploads', 'ImageController@adminIndex')->name('admin.images.index');
Route::get('/uploads/{image}', 'ImageController@adminShow')->name('admin.image.indivisual');
Route::get('/uploads/request', 'ImageController@imageRequests')->name('admin.images.request');
Route::get('/uploads/request/{image}', 'ImageController@individualRequest')->name('admin.images.request.individual');
Route::post('/uploads/accept', 'ImageController@acceptImage')->name('admin.accept.image');
Route::post('/uploads/decline/', 'ImageController@declineImage')->name('admin.decline.image');
Route::get('/uploads/all', 'ImageController@index')->name('admin.images.list');
```

The thing that confuses me is that changing **uploads** to **images** for these two routes solved the problem and they work just fine.

```
Route::get('/uploads', 'ImageController@adminIndex')->name('admin.images.index');
Route::get('/uploads/{image}', 'ImageController@adminShow')->name('admin.image.indivisual');
Route::get('/images/request', 'ImageController@imageRequests')->name('admin.images.request');
Route::get('/uploads/request/{image}', 'ImageController@individualRequest')->name('admin.images.request.individual');
Route::post('/uploads/accept', 'ImageController@acceptImage')->name('admin.accept.image');
Route::post('/uploads/decline/', 'ImageController@declineImage')->name('admin.decline.image');
Route::get('/images/all', 'ImageController@index')->name('admin.images.list');
```

I have tried `php artisan route:clear`.

Also, there are no folders in the public directory to create any conflicts.

Note: All the routes are grouped in

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => 'role:administrator|auth'], function () {
  // Other routes in this group are working just fine. No issues.
});
```

Appreciate the help.

Comment: You just show the routes, how do you intend to call / utilize? that's need to be cleared as well.

Comment: I have called them using their names. Eg: `<a href="{{ route('admin.images.request') }}"> Link </a>`. Also there is no issues with roles and permission. @Gabriel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please move the router into last of list:

```
Route::get('/uploads/{image}', 'ImageController@adminShow')->name('admin.image.indivisual');
```

Because It includes `Route::get('/uploads/request'` and `Route::get('/uploads/all'` then It override this two routers

So code of routers list:

```
Route::get('/uploads', 'ImageController@adminIndex')->name('admin.images.index');
Route::get('/uploads/request', 'ImageController@imageRequests')->name('admin.images.request');
Route::get('/uploads/request/{image}', 'ImageController@individualRequest')->name('admin.images.request.individual');
Route::post('/uploads/accept', 'ImageController@acceptImage')->name('admin.accept.image');
Route::post('/uploads/decline/', 'ImageController@declineImage')->name('admin.decline.image');
Route::get('/uploads/all', 'ImageController@index')->name('admin.images.list');
// move to last 
Route::get('/uploads/{image}', 'ImageController@adminShow')->name('admin.image.indivisual');
```

Comment: Thanks, @Ryan. Completely forget about Routes Priority. You saved my day.